# Powershell script to send messages

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm writing a Script which reads an array of computers from the active directory.
Then a foreach loop should try to send a Message with msg.exe to each of the clients.

```
    Param(
    [string]$Nachricht
    )

# Computerkonten aus dem AD beziehen
$Computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "LT1130"' -Property Name,lastLogonDate -SearchBase "OU=Clients,DC=domain,DC=intern" | where {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=01_Deaktiviert,*")})

foreach ($a in $Computers) {
    msg console /server:$a.Name $Nachricht
    Write-Host Nachricht an $a.Name gesendet.
    
}
```

If I run this it says "Error 1722 getting session names?"

This happens no matter if I send it to the console session or to "*" all sessions.

Comment: Change `msg console /server:$a.Name $Nachricht` to `msg console /server:$($a.Name) $Nachricht`

Answer (score 0):

**So, I am guessing this is to message every laptop (like when you want to shut them down)**

Did you try this? (en Deutsch)

```
 #.\Msg-Laptops.ps1
 $Nachricht = "Geh nach Hause!"
    Param(
    [string]$Nachricht
    )

# Abrufen von Computerkonten aus dem AD
$Computers = (Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=*LT1130*)" -Property CN,DistinguishedName -SearchBase "OU=Clients,DC=domain,DC=intern" | where {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=01_Deaktiviert,*")})
foreach ($a in $Computers) { 
$a = $a.NAME+".intern"
    msg console /server:$a.DNSHostName $Nachricht
    Write-Host "$Nachricht to $a Sent"
    
}
```